# Is it okay to duplicate function argument name when in implementation and in calling?

Tags: c++, function, scope

If I have

```
#include <iostream>
int fun(int,int);

int main(void)
{
   int foo=3;
   int bar=5;
   std::cout << fun(foo,bar);
}

int fun(int foo, int bar){ return foo+bar; }
```

Will there (possibly) be confusion (by either human or complier!) regarding conflicting names `foo` and `bar`, one in the function definition, one in main program body?
So far I find the result all correct, but it is better to know the best practice.
Indeed I often run out of imagination, and name the two occurrences (as in the example) to be the same.

(I have wondered this for years; this is so basic that I am sure someone must have asked before in the long history of SO, but I cannot find any by now. If duplicated, by all means let me know.)

Comment: As you ask this question you probably need to read about scope. There is nothing wrong about having variables with same name in different scopes and depending on coding style (completely opinion based) it can be the default to use the same name for the actual parameters you pass to a function as those parameters are named also inside the function.

Comment: Then what about languages such as Python where there is no concept of scope?

Comment: then its a different question, because this one is about c++ :P. I am complete beginner in python, but i cannot believe that it does not have a concept of scope

Comment: Okay, I regret that I have mixed things up... I have also python in mind when asking this, and I thought the question can be answered generally. But if it is not, since I took a C/C++ example, we shall focus on C/C++ right now (maybe I will ask for a different language next time).

Comment: @Aminopterin The answer's the same for Python, which also has lexical scope (like most languages for the last half-century or so).

Comment: @Aminopterin The scope in Python is implicit, since there is no variable declaration as in C++, but there is a notion of scope anyway. Function-local variables in different functions, for instance, can have the same name but they are still distinct, in the vast majority of programming languages.

Comment: I do this all the time, and I think it's actually a good practice as it helps you follow the data through. It also makes refactoring a function into smaller pieces easier.

Comment: I think it is @Rob K who actually answers my problem XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compiler, each variable is associated with a scope defined by the language standard then there must not exist any cases of mis-understanding. If in a case at which compilers cannot decide the scope of a variable then an ambiguous compiling error is raised.

Example: Same name, but different scope.

```
int x = 10;

void func() {
  // the definition of local x below hides global x in current scope
  int x = x; // local x is assigned value of global x
  x = 5; // local x is assigned 5, this does not affect global x
  printf("local x = %d\n", x);
}

int main() {
  func();

  printf("global x = %d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

To see how compilers can treat variables with the same name but different scope, read more at [How does a C compiler differentiate a local and a global variable of the same name?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-C-compiler-differentiate-a-local-and-a-global-variable-of-the-same-name)

To human, it's called naming convention. You are free to use any valid names to name your variables but you are recommended to follow some consistent rules - that will make your code a lot more readable and maintainable.